# What does the access log format signifies

Tags: apache, logging

What does the following format signifies?

```
"GET /shipments HTTP/1.1" 200 1339
```

**GET** is the type of request

**/shipments** is the url hit

**200** is the status code

What are `HTTP/1.1 and 1339`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, HTTP/1.1 is the HTTP version the client used to make its request, and 1339 the length of the response in bytes.

Check out the documentation for the [mod_log_config](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html) for a list of all the variables that can be used in log files.

Comment: Length ? As in time taken?

Comment: No, the length in bytes, i.e. how long the response was.

Comment: Can you please provide your feed-back on this question as well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24402657/fix-a-crashed-server